# Safari refresh loop with webpack-dev-server in https mode

Tags: javascript, safari, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I encountered a strange issue when I was testing a JS module on Safari Version 9.0.1 (11601.2.7.2)

So I am using webpack-dev-server with standard HMR configuration (but with `https: true`) and the browser keeps refreshing even if I don't make updates to my source file. In fact it is stuck in a refresh loop.

When I open the inspector console I see this error briefly before reload:

`WebSocket network error: OSStatus Error -9807: Invalid certificate chain`

and then just before refresh

```
[WDS] Disconnected!
[WDS] App updated. Reloading...
```

Probably has something to do with the self-signed certificate verification failing. The server's running on `https://localhost:1111` and I have visited the page in another tab to accept the certificates.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

pass the **inline: false** parameter to your webpack devServer config, something like:

```
devServer: {
    hot: false,
    contentBase: './dist',
    https: true,
    port: 8000,
    inline: false,
},
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, make sure you have a valid certificate for your SSL connection. This quelches the bug in Safari without using `inline: false`. You can use ZeroSSL https://zerossl.com/ or Let's Encrypt https://letsencrypt.org/ to get free, valid certificates.

Comment: Another way to avoid `inline: false` is to make your iPhone trust your server certificate. Follow this procedure: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7738477 (first answer worked for me)